# Can not push Docker Image to Artifactory in Jenkins pipeline using Artifactory plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, docker-registry

I'm using a Docker Registry on Artifactory. I'm able to pull/push images using docker commands. Now I try to push an image using a Jenkins pipline.

The image is called `registry-url/docker/image:latest`.
I have a docker repository on Artifactory which is called `docker`. (I'm able to pull and push to this repo using docker commands).

This stage describes my Artifactory configuration:

```
...
        stage('Deploy Docker image'){
            steps {
                script {
                    def server = Artifactory.server 'xxx'
                    def rtDocker = Artifactory.docker server: server
                    def buildInfo = rtDocker.push('registry-url/image:latest', 'docker')
                    //also tried:
                    //def buildInfo = rtDocker.push('registry-url/docker/image:latest', 'docker') 
                    //the above results in registry/docker/docker/image..
                    server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
                }
            }
        }
...
```

When I use different paths I face the `manifest.json` error which is probably normal.
I'm able to download the manifest.json manually on: `https://registry-url/artifactory/docker/image/latest/manifest.json`.

I'm using a pretty new version of Docker on Jenkins:

```
Docker version 18.01.0-ce, build 03596f51b1
```

So far so good. But When I run the pipeline I receive the following error in Jenkins (it takes 50 seconds):

```
Pushing image: registry-url/image:latest
...
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Could not push image: unknown: Not Found
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.PushImageResultCallback.awaitSuccess(PushImageResultCallback.java:49)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.docker.utils.DockerUtils.pushImage(DockerUtils.java:60)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.docker.utils.DockerAgentUtils$3.call(DockerAgentUtils.java:213)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.docker.utils.DockerAgentUtils$3.call(DockerAgentUtils.java:205)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
  ...
```

In Artifactory logs I see:

```
2018-04-25 14:24:26,663 [http-nio-8081-exec-xx] [ERROR] (o.a.a.d.r.DockerResource:153) - Unsupported docker v2 repository request for 'image'
2018-04-25 14:24:46,684 [http-nio-8081-exec-xx] [ERROR] (o.a.a.d.r.DockerResource:153) - Unsupported docker v2 repository request for 'image'
2018-04-25 14:24:46,689 [http-nio-8081-exec-xx] [ERROR] (o.a.a.d.r.DockerResource:153) - Unsupported docker v2 repository request for 'image'
2018-04-25 14:24:46,702 [http-nio-8081-exec-xx] [ERROR] (o.a.a.d.r.DockerResource:153) - Unsupported docker v2 repository request for 'image'
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Based on this [issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-16074) I went back to my initial idea:

```
def buildInfo = rtDocker.push('registry-url/docker/image:latest', 'docker')
```

I tried the build again. Error:

```
Could not find manifest.json in Artifactory in the following path: https://registry-url/artifactory/docker/docker/image/latest/manifest.json
```

Two times 'docker' in the path and it seems not to work. BUT when I check in Artifactory the image is there... I can also pull the image. It seems to be fine but still the jenkins build is failing.

Artifactory Plugin: 2.15.1
Artifactory Version: 5.10.3

Is this really a bug which will be fixed soon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Artifcatory can be configured as a docker registry either with or without a reverse proxy.
It looks like your Artifactory is not configured using a reverse-proxy (proxy-less configuration). You can read more about the configuration options [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-GettingStartedwithArtifactoryProOn-Prem).

Version 2.16.1 of the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin added support for proxy-less configuration. Upgrading your Artifactory Plugin should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try tomorrow and let you know if it works. I see the new update is available which wasn't at the time of asking. :)

Comment: @lvthillo I believe, I'm facing the same kind of problem, from Jenkins, so I cross-checked by pushing the image from local. question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092140/docker-push-fails-manifest-invalid)
is there any way to solve it from the client's end? without touching the registry side? [as right now I don't have access to those.]

Answer (score 2):

Try following this example. Here we have Jenkins pipeline to pull/push docker image to/from Artifactory: https://github.com/jfrogtraining/kubernetes_example/blob/master/docker-app/Jenkinsfile#L43