# docker push fails : manifest invalid

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

When trying to do `docker push <IMAGE>` to a private docker image registry,
getting an error saying **manifest invalid**

along with the error, it's giving some **`[DEPRECATION NOTICE]`**, which might be the cause of the failure as well.

**Note:** After getting this error and failing the `docker push` command. (in `ci/cd` it's failing the job, I'm guessing its throwing `exit 1` ), when I check back in the registry, the image is present.

> In the same docker registry, there is other images present as well. and they also are going through the same CI/CD pipeline. but for them, there is no issue detected. is there any possibility that the issue is originating from the `Dockerfile`? (*Although it used to work previously, with the same Dockerfile*)

I have doubled check that, the image `version` (e.g: `<IMAGE_NAME>:0.0.1-5e90df92ed140-development`) I'm pushing is not present in the registry.

I have also referred to multiple questions and issues regarding this and crossed checked the

- The user has permission to push & pull images
- manifests having the same numbers of `fsLayers` as `history`

**Note:** We are using **JFrog** Artifactory version to 6.12.2

Docker Version (*In my local machine, where it fails as well. with the same message*):

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.4
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.10
 Git commit:        9013bf5
 Built:             Thu Oct 17 23:44:48 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.4
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.10
  Git commit:       9013bf5
  Built:            Thu Oct 17 23:50:38 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

**Error:**

```
596280599f68: Layer already exists
5d6cbe0dbcf9: Pushed 
[DEPRECATION NOTICE] registry v2 schema1 support will be removed in an upcoming release. Please contact admins of the xxxxxxx.docker.repositories.xxxxxx.com registry NOW to avoid future disruption. More information at https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/deprecated-schema-v1/
manifest invalid: manifest invalid
```

Comment: What version of docker client, engine, and registry? How are you building images?

Comment: @BMitch updated the question with the docker engine and client version. not sure about the registry version though. 
when I check `manifest.json` there is `schemaVersion:1`

Comment: @BMitch I'm right now building using docker build comand, also the same facing when building using Jenkins.

Answer (score 23):

Ran into the same problem.  The issue was that repo does not let you over-write images tags.  I changed the tag to a new major version.

Comment: are you saying that the image tag already exists in the repo already and when trying to push?
if that is so, then I have checked multiple times, it does not exist till the docker push fails.

Answer (score 10):

Ran into the samish problem with 6.16.
The issue was authorization related. I had to add the Delete / Override Repository Action as well to the build agent user.

The build agent only had write permissions, and the second time it built the image with the same tag, it could not overwrite the manifest! This made the client to roll back to schema1 for some reason.

Figured it out through the System Logs of Artifactory.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info, but for me, the user I'm using to push, have that permission.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Humblefool till now no,

Answer (score 2):

This can happen after your system (e.g. **Ubuntu**) upgrades **docker-ce-cli** to a newer version e.g. from **5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-bionic** to **5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic**

If upgrading your docker-registry to a newer version is not an option at the moment, then you might try to downgrade your **docker-ce-cli** to some previous version.
To see the list of available versions:

```
sudo apt-cache policy docker-ce

sudo apt-cache policy docker-ce-cli
```

To downgrade to previous version run:

```
sudo apt install docker-ce=5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-bionic docker-ce-cli=5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
```

Same method can be applied to downgrade **docker-ce** package.

Check version:

```
docker --version
```

Then try to push again:

```
docker push your-docker-registry.com:5000/myprojects/my-postgresql-image:latest
```

*Please note that keeping your software up-to-date might improve security of your system(s)!*

Answer (score 2):

I had the same condition as user3749775: The problem was that the image already existed.
I just want to add the solution: I added this and then I was able to overwrite images:

```
docker login -u <user> -p <password> <address of my artifactory>
```

Strangely, I was able to push the image without logging in, as long as the image did not exist yet.

I would have added this as a comment under the original response. But I don't have reputation to add comments on responses.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing my artifacts into artifactory failed with the same reason `manifest invalid: manifest invalid` due to the previous docker image existed. Removing the docker image resolved the issue.

Error

```
The push refers to repository [xxxxx.com/foo]
83850d400bdd: Pushed
309acb279757: Pushed
ebf469e844a6: Layer already exists
94c94d3b2e6b: Layer already exists
manifest invalid: manifest invalid
 Error: The command exited with status 1
```

To remove the docker image

```
docker image rm <name>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it looks as if a manifest file got corrupted somehow, 
and the solution was:

1. Delete the images with the tags that failed to upload 
   (this includes their manifest files, of course)
2. Manually run the **Garbage Collection*** 
   (go to: Administration > Artifactory > Advanced > Maintenance)

---

*in Artifactory 7.x this requires pressing the Garbage-Collection's `Run Now` button some 20 times... - see: 
[Why does removing/deleting old artifacts is not affecting the Artifactory disk space usage?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-does-removing-deleting-old-artifacts-is-not-affecting-the-artifactory-disk-space-usage/)